# snmpset throwing noAccess error

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

While setting a OID using `snmpset` command I am getting a `noAccess` error ?

I am able to get the OID value. I am using `net-snmp` for agent configuration and I think I have configured `snmpd.conf` correctly. The OID is also read-write in 
the MIB definition.  Here is the output :

```
snmpget -v 2c -c myprivate 10.10.1.19 SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: rajesh.kumar@gmail.com

snmpset -v2c -c myprivate 10.10.1.19 SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 s rajesh.kumar3@gmail.com.com
Error in packet.
Reason: noAccess
Failed object: SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0
```

I have configured `snmpd.conf` properly with community and access.

Answer (score 0):

Double check agent's `snmpd.conf`'s `rwcommunity`. The default is disabled i.e. ...

```
# rwcommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-write access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid]

#rwcommunity  private
```

Have you have set `rocommunity` to be `myprivate` ? Try setting the rw one to `mypublic` and the ro one to `myprivate` and try again.

Also look at answers to this SO question [NoAccess error in snmpset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559926/noaccess-error-in-snmpset)