# snmpset gives error "No community name specified"

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am understanding of to extend snmp agent by custom MIBS and following this tutorial:

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent

I was able to compile the net-snmp package with custom MIB file alongwith the C file and the Header file. I am also able to run the snmpd agent using below command:

**sudo snmpd -f -V -L -d -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf**

Also, snmpget is working as expected by the tutorial:

**$ snmpget -v 2c 192.168.1.105 -c public NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0**

Output: NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0 = INTEGER: 2

However snmpset is failing with error: "No community name specified"

**snmpset -v 2c 192.168.1.105 -c public NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0 = 5**

I also tried with private for community string:

**snmpset -v 2c 192.168.1.105 -c private NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0 = 5**

Still same error.
Why is snmpset not working ?

Here is my snmpd.conf file: (relevant sections)
######################################################################################

```
agentAddress udp:192.168.1.105:161
## ACCESS CONTROL
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
#rocommunity public  localhost
 rocommunity public
 rwcommunity private
 rouser   authOnlyUser
com2sec readonly default public
com2sec readwrite default private
```